# How can I make skype calls in Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, skype, microphone

Today I spent more than an hour trying to get Skype set up on my Linux box (Debian testing), but I couldn't make my microphone to work correctly. So I hear the other person talking, but they can't hear me. I am running KDE 4.3 and Skype 2.1 Beta. What do I need to do to get it working?

Comment: Does the microphone work in other applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my microphone didn't work in any other application either. After some fiddling with mixer settings, I found out that the Capture switch was disabled and muted. After fixing this and setting Front Mic as the Input Source everything started working.

Its a bit of a shame that the default mixer settings are still not what the average user would expect.

Thanks for the hint @Nifle

Answer (score 1):

I've used audio with Skype and GNOME before. I'm suspecting you don't have the audio input set properly. Open options (ctrl+o) and go to sound devices, check the input there. Likely that's set to PulseAudio, Ideally KDE needs to use the same audio system.